# Not sure what this Scala Syntax is doing

Tags: scala

I'm fairly new to Scala and I was wondering what the following line of code is doing:

```
class E{
  val (a: A, b: B, c:C, d:D) = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is it making an assignment (because of the val?) and then executing the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

val defines a variable that cannot be reassigned. Then the `(a, b, ..)` notation exposes a tuple with values a, b, ... to be assigned.

Here's an example you can run:

```
// define types
type A = String
type B = String
type C = String
type D = String

// adding tuple@ to show a,b,c,d are components of a tuple aka extraction
val tuple@(a: A, b: B, c:C, d:D) = {
  ("aString", "bString", "cString", "dString")
}

println(tuple)
```

Additionally, you can specify types more explicitly such as

```
val tuple@(a: A, b: B, c:C, d:D): (A, B, C, D) = {
  ("aString": A, "bString": B, "cString": C, "dString": D)
}
```

And the output is:

```
defined type alias A
defined type alias B
defined type alias C
defined type alias D
tuple: (A, B, C, D) = (aString,bString,cString,dString)
a: A = aString
b: B = bString
c: C = cString
d: D = dString
(aString,bString,cString,dString)
```

Comment: Does this mean that, unless I assign name to (a:A, ...), I cannot reference it in my later code? And does the name have to have the form "name@"?

Comment: with out the name `tuple` binded to the tuple, the elements must be referred separately by `a, b,...`. You can always bind manually later with `val t4 = (a, b, c, d)`. However, in most cases, you do the opposite where you get a tuple, then extract the elements with pattern matching such `tuple3 match { case (a: String, b: String, c: String) => ??? }`

Answer (score 3):

It's *execute the body, then destructure it's result*:

```
val (a: A, b: B, c:C, d:D) = {
    ...
}
```

First, the body produces some result (which is expected to be tuple*), then this tuple broken down into it's elements, each element is assigned to `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` respectively.

You probably have seen this code in Java:

```
int x = 1, y = 2, z = 4;
// now x is 1, y is 2, z is 4
```

Or even this code in python:

```
>>> x, y = 1, 2
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
```

Scala takes this on the next level, with a feature called **destructuring assignment**, and while it doesn't allow Java and Python syntaxes, it's far more flexible because it allows you not only the similar experience (via using of tuples):

```
val (x, y) = (1, 2)
```

But also generalized and [extensible concept](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112) of such use case of pattern matching, e.g. on arrays:

```
val xs = Array(1,2,3,4)
val Array(first, second, _*) = xs  // _* mean I don't care about the rest of elements
// first: Int = 1
// second: Int = 2
```

On lists:

```
val head::tail = List(1,2,3,4)
head: Int = 1
tail: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

And in many other cases.

You may think that this operation somehow destroys original value, but usually it's not (unless custom **extractor** function is side-effecting)

* tuple is a kinda like immutable collection of finite known size, each element of it can be directly addressed which `._x` method, like `foo._1` for the first one, `foo._2` for the second one. Tuples in scala has syntax sugar -- braces.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `scala -Xprint:parser -e "val (a, b) = (1, 2)"` to desugar the code. What actually happened is:

```
val x$1 = (1, 2) match {
  case Tuple2((a @ _), (b @ _)) => Tuple2(a, b)
}
val a = x$1._1
val b = x$1._2
```